# How to pass params from click to live function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions click and live. I want to pass a parameter from click to live.I tried something like below but it's not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var test = 'test' ;                               
  jQuery('.item a').click(test);//pass an argument from here
});

jQuery('.item a').live('click',function(e,test) {
  alert(test);//access argument here
});
```

Is this possible?

Update:

```
function init() {   
    //When you click on a link
    jQuery('.item a').live('click',function(e,test) {
        alert(test);
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(init);
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var test= 'test';
    jQuery('.item a').trigger('click', test);   
});
```

I am expecting an alert.

Edit2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function($){
        $('.item').each(function() {
            $(this)[0].oncontextmenu = function() { return false }
          });
        $.fn.ctrl = function(key, callback) {
            if(typeof key != 'object') key = [key];
            callback = callback || function(){ return false; }
            return $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                var ret = true;
                $.each(key,function(i,k){
                    if(e.keyCode == k.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) && e.ctrlKey) {
                        ret = callback(e);
                    }
                });
                return ret;
            });
        };

        $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
            $(window).ctrl(['a','s','c']);
            return this.each(function() {           
                $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
                       .css({'-moz-user-select':'none',
                            '-o-user-select':'none',
                            '-khtml-user-select':'none',
                            '-webkit-user-select':'none',
                            '-ms-user-select':'none',
                            'user-select':'none'})
                       .each(function() {
                            $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
                            .bind('selectstart',function(){ return false; });
                       });
            });
        };
        $('.item').disableSelection();
    })(jQuery);             

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `trigger()` instead, which allows you to pass arguments;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var test = 'test' ;                               
  jQuery('.item a').trigger('click', test); //pass an argument from here
});

jQuery('.item a').live('click',function(e,test) {
  alert(test);//access argument here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this should work but may be I am doing something wrong.And not getting what I expected.I am updating the code  if you can help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Will this affect your code if I disable right click for '.item-232 a'?

Comment: @Irfan: Shouldn't do. Unless the code you're using to disable right clicks is preventing *all* mouse events propagating

Answer (score 1):

Or You can use hidden field to store params need to pass then read it in click function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var test = 'test' ;
  jQuery('#hiddenID').val(test);
  jQuery('.item a').click(test);//pass an argument from here
});

jQuery('.item a').live('click',function(e,test) {
  var test = jQuery('#hiddenID').val();
  alert(test);//access argument here
});
```

Comment: You could even use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) in this circumstance, rather than relying on hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var test = 'test' ;                               
    $('.item a').trigger({type:'click', myParam:test}); // pass the event object with param
});

$('.item a').live('click',function(e) {
    alert(e.myParam); //access param here
});
```

Also remember `live` is deprecated instead use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**Update:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var test= 'test';
    $('.item a').trigger({type:'click', myParam:test});
});
$('.item a').live('click',function(e) {
    alert(e.myParam); //access param here
});
```